# Shadow effect not working as expected

Tags: wordpress, shadow

I'm trying to put a shadow effect to my wordpress website (I use Visual composer) but on the two sides of the box to which I try to put the shadow I get "extra" white space like shown in the image below :
[image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iXCK4.png)
Can anyone help me get rid of the blank space on the sides?

Comment: Please show us the css and html.  Without it's impossible to help you.

Answer (score 0):

The CSS code is : .hafashadow {
box-shadow: 1px 1px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2)
}

It's applied as an additional CSS class to my column using Visual composer.

And here is how the HTML looks like 
[Image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lUvab.png)